# как понять почему не создается дректория mkdir

Tags: php

пытаюсь создать директорию следующим образом

```
 if (file_exists($uploadPath)) {
 } else {
     if (mkdir($uploadPath, 0777, true)) {
     }else{
           $error = error_get_last();
           return var_dump($error['message']);
     }
 }
```

получаю `null` error.log тоже молчит не подскажите, доступы вроде тоже есть на все папки по пути

Comment: Какой каталог в является текущим в момент выполнения кода?
Чему равен $uploadPath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все верно, вы проверяете существует ли файл

```
 if (file_exists($uploadPath))
```

и если нет, пытаетесь создать папку, но у вас в $uploadPath не директория, а путь к файлу, вместе с файлом !

вам необходимо сделать так ...

```
if (file_exists($uploadPath)) {

} else {
if (mkdir(pathinfo($uploadPath)['dirname'], 0777, true)) {

}
else {
   $error = error_get_last();
   return var_dump($error['message']);
}
}
```

Все зависит что у вас в переменной $uploadPath, если у вас там путь к папке то вместо file_exists необходимо использовать is_dir. Тогда проверка будет логичнее, если папки нет, то создать ее